# how to skip fist when-then call in junit

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, stubbing

I want to write a Junit test for a Java code similar to the code below. In the code, `method()` is called 2 times. In my Junit test, I have something like this `when(method()).thenThrow(exception);` but I want this when-then to be triggered on the 2nd `method()` call, and not on the 1st `method()` call. So, how can I do that?

```
class Example {
    public void example() {
        OtherClass.method(); //1st method call
        /*
        * doing something
        */
        OtherClass.method(); //2nd method call
    }
}
```

Comment: If `method()` is on the class you are testing, then you can't stub it, because that would require mocking the object you want to test.

Comment: @tgdavies the `method()` is from some other class.

Comment: Then it would be `otherClass.method()` -- unless you mean a superclass?

Comment: @tgdavies I have edited. But what's solution for my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can repeat Mockito's `do...()` methods when you mock a void method:

```
        doNothing().doThrow(new RuntimeException("test")).when(mock).method();
```

The effects will happen in sequence if there are multiple calls to `method`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Spy for your instance what are testing.

Spies are like mocks but you can stub some methods of the same class what you are testing
--well this answer was for your first question

After edit, you can just chain the second stub

when(method()).thenThrow(exception).thenThrow(exception);